# NameError while calling another function inside a function

Tags: python

Why am I getting a name error for `pays_bill`?

```
error: NameError: name 'pays_bill' is not defined
```

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self,total):
        self.billamt=total

    def pays_bill(self,amount):
        print("maaz  pays bill amount of Rs.",amount)

    def purchases(self):
        discount=(.05*self.billamt)
        amount=(self.billamt-discount)
        pays_bill(self,amount)

x=Customer(1000)
x.purchases()
```

Comment: You need to use `self.pays_bill(...)`

Comment: thanks a lot brother. really thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self,total):
        self.billamt=total

    def pays_bill(self,amount):
        print("maaz  pays bill amount of Rs.",amount)

    def purchases(self):
        discount=(.05*self.billamt)
        amount=(self.billamt-discount)
        self.pays_bill(amount)

x=Customer(1000)
x.purchases()
```